# What is the World Record for Most Pieces En Prise in a Chess Game?

Tags: online-chess, computer-chess, records

Does anyone know what the world record is for most pieces en prise in a game of chess is?

Edit: I mean in a game that has actually been played, not a constructed game.

Edit: by en prise I mean can be captured by any piece even if there is a recapture next turn.

Comment: You may have to clarify, but I assume that you exclude 'games' that weren't actually played.  (There are construction that may qualify, except that were not played to the point of the position.)  Can you verify that that is your intention, or clarify in case it isn't.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/longest-period-with-each-piece-hanging

Comment: I think Tim Krabbé adresses this on his unmissable blog, but with the restrictive definition of "en prise" meaning "being targetted by a pawn". Can you precise what is your definition of "en prise" ? (it could also mean "can be captured", "can be captured and isn't protected (/ protected enough)", with variations whether the attacking piece is stronger, or pinned, etc.)

Comment: I always thought the phrase was "on freeze", which makes no sense